# windows azure migrate a VM across datacenters

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have an azure vm (windows server 2012) in data region X. Azure has just opened a new data center in geo region Y which is much closer to me. How can I easily mygrate my VM? Short downtimes are tolerable.

If I blob-copy the VM and then copy to a new container in the new datacenter, I'm not seeing how to attach the VHD as osdisk to a new VM when creating the VM via the management portal. Is this process only possible via PowerShell. Any other methods?

If only possible via PowerShell, pointers appreciated.

Comment: This may be a workable path via the management portal: http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/moving-system-drive-windows-azure/

Comment: Devaluing the question for "lack of research" is a bit trigger-happy here. There are several "half answers" to this question which I indeed found (one shared above). In the end, the answer is not readily available and is: The management portal provides the features needed for this (one place or the other) except for the cross-region copy of the blob. For this you'll need PowerShell (examples available) or specialty tools such as the one mentioned below here in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the machines (including the blob-storage) as exampled here:

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/07/04/how-to-move-windows-azure-virtual-machines-from-one-subscription-to-another/

He explains how you can attach your disk from the portal as well.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, the VHD copy tools that I was using were having problems with connectivity/copy between two continents. Once the copies were ok, the above worked perfectly.